# How do I Remove an Apostrophe in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

This is for one of our challenges on Thinkful for the prep course so this is not actually a question that I can get in trouble for cheating on or anything like that but I pasted the question and the code that is expecting the results below oh, I just can't get this right I've tried everything.

> Diego has lyrics for two songs he wants to display on his website. The first is "Seen a Thousand Things" and the other is "We're All Light". The songs titles are stored in the database in lowercase text and without punctuation so to find the right lyrics, we need to transform the songTitle variable to match what is stored in the database. Can you use your knowledge of string methods to: 1) lowercase the songTitle variable and 2)remove all apostrophes from songTitle?

```
Time: 6762msPassed: 1Failed: 1Exit Code: 1
Test Results:
Seen
 a Thousand Things
should lowercase the text in the song title 'Seen a Thousand Things'
We're all Light
should remove the apostrophe and lowercase the text in the song title 'We're all light'
Test Failed
Failure
Error: expect(received).toMatch(expected)

Expected substring: "were all light"
Received string:    "we're all light"
Completed in 3ms
Failures
  ● We're all Light › should remove the apostrophe and lowercase the text in the song title 'We're all light'

    expect(received).toMatch(expected)

    Expected substring: "were all light"
    Received string:    "we're all light"

      13 |   it("should remove the apostrophe and lowercase the text in the song title 'We're all light'", () => {
      14 |     let songTitle = "We're all light"
    > 15 |     expect(setSongTitle(songTitle)).toMatch("were all light");
         |                                     ^
      16 |   })
      17 | })

      at Object.toMatch (test/script.test.js:15:37)
```

Here are the methods I've tried:

```
songTitle.replace("[\s']","","ALL"); (failed), 
songTitle.replace(/[']+/g,""));
```

Comment: Note that the result is also expected to be lower case, which your code isn’t even attempting…

Comment: Your second method should work. Did you assign the result back to the variable?

Comment: You can simplify it to just `songTitle.replace(/'/g, "")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I'd advise against using regex with the `g` flag unless you fully understand the implications.

Comment: I'd suggest trying https://regexr.com/ as you figure out the appropriate regular expression. You can provide your input and it'll visualize and help you understand what characters your regex is capturing.